# Django different USERNAME field for registration and for login

Tags: python, django

I want to have a USERNAME_FIELD for registration of my users (lets say this field is the country ID) and another one for login (internal id).

My process is as follows:

- User registers with name, email and COUNTRY_ID (as username_field) aswell with a password.
- Next, an admin validates this information and confirms the registration of this user and an automatic internal ID is assigned.
- The user is then informed (via email) of this action and can therefore login with this internal id.

Is it possible then to have a different USERNAME_FIELD for registration and for login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username is supposed to be unique (obviously - how else would you identify your user at login ?), so in it's current formulation, your question doesn't really make sense. If you don't want the users to provide a username when applying for registration, then your question is not about having "a USERNAME_FIELD for registration and another for login", it's about "how to allow the user to register *without* providing a value for the USERNAME_FIELD".

One possible solution is to use a system-provided unique random value (ie an uuid or something built from user's ip + current timestamp + some random value) as temporary username.

Another is to use a distinct model for registrations and only create the User during validation process (which, if you're using the default `User` model, will help telling the yet unvalidated registrations).

In both cases you'll of course have to write your own forms and views (preferably delegating what can be to the `contrib.auth` app - don't try to reinvent the wheel either).

Comment: Maybe my formulation wasn't the best but your answer helped me